# How to use an object of a class in a method of the same class?

Tags: java

My problem is the following :

I have 2 classes : `MainActivity` and `Compartment`.

`MainActivity` creates an array `myComp[][]` of `Compartment`.
`Compartment` has a static variable called `PpN2`, and a public method that calculates `PpN2`.

This method has to calculate `myComp[x][y]`.`PpN2` which is a function of `myComp[x-1][y].PpN2`.

Question : how can I access `myComp[x-1][y].PpN2` in the method that calculates `myComp[x][y].PpN2` ?

Comment: I am confused. Better show us some code.

Comment: ...For `PpN2` to be a static variable does not make sense, given everything you've told us.

Comment: The same way you access `myComp[x][y]`?

Comment: Why are you using such cryptic names for variables like "PpN2"?  And do you **really** need those two-dimensional arrays in OOP?

Comment: Example code would help a lot. It's hard to understand what you're talking about, but there seems to be no reason you can't directly access `myComp[x-1][y]` from the method in question. Agreed on the cryptic names...

Comment: If `PpN2` is a static variable, it should be the same for every instance of `Compartment`. There should be no need to refer to `myComp[x-1][y]`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is static variable, you can access using reference (or) using class name.

Example:

```
Compartment.PpN2
```

Remember because of static variable, myComp[x][y] (or)myComp[x-1][y] references updates same variable.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need `PpN2` to be an instance variable instead of static, and have `MainActivity` pass `myComp[x-1][y]` into `myComp[x][y].calcPpN2()` or whatever the calc method is called.

Alternatively, you could have `Compartment` hold a reference to the previous one that the `PpN2` calc depends on, and pass it in during construction.

The reason that `PpN2` should probably be static is that, being static, its value is shared by all instances of type `Compartment`. As an instance variable, each individual `Compartment` object will have its own `PpN2` value.